# What does host netgroup mean in the context of sudoHost in Sudoers LDAP Schema

Tags: sudo, ldap

ref: https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.7.4p6/sudoers.ldap.man.html

What does host netgroup mean in the context of sudoHost in Sudoers LDAP Schema.

Can you please give an example of how to set this up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A host netgroup contains a list of hosts.

```
myhostnetgroup     (server1) (server2) (server3)
```

Refer to the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/5/netgroup).  If you want your netgroups in LDAP check [here](http://directory.fedoraproject.org/docs/389ds/howto/howto-netgroups.html) for some information.

When you reference the netgroup in your sudo config, it will grant access to any of the hosts in the netgroup so you don't have to list them out explicitly.

Comment: Can the host netgroup be defined in LDAP?

Comment: Yes, added a reference link to my answer.